# Get item by another element from list in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to figure out, in `Type Script` how get one item from `this.myList` by another element. If I add elements to `private myList: any = [];` this way:

```
  this.myList.push({ id: i, name: myName, UID: obj.UID },);
```

where `id: i` is a loop iteration number, `name: myName` is a username, and `UID: obj.UID` is a non sequential specific number, then `myList` content is something like this:

```
    id| myName   | UID
    -------------------
    0 | sally    | 345
    1 | vikram   | 5487
    2 | kim      | 12
    3 | roy      | 2134
```

My goal and desired result is to find `ID: obj.ID` by `myName` value. For example get `UID` value: **12** by `myName`: **kim**

it works if  I use it this way, with given list:

```
 let a = [{id: 0, name: 'sally', uid: 345}, {id: 1, name: 'vikram', uid: 5487}, {id: 2, name: 'kim', uid: 12}, {id: 3, name: 'roy', uid: 2134}];
 let wantedname = 'kim';
 let found = a.find(e => e.name === wantedname);
 found.uid;
```

but if I'm trying to use it with my real list, I got `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined`:

with space, because I got space in check-box values:

```
 val srcVal = ' ' + this.searchName;
```

or even without space:

```
 val srcVal = this.searchName; 

 let found = this.myList.find(e => e.name === srcVal);
```

or:

```
  let a = this.myList;
  let found = a.find(e => e.name === srcVal);
```

In  `console.log("Name: " + this.searchName, " UID: ",  found.uid );` `found.uid` is `undefined`.

It is same structure, not sure what is wrong with it

Answer (score 1):

Given how you've currently structured the data, this will mean iterating over the list until you find the element you want. Something like:

```
findByName(searchName: string) {
    const found = this.myList.find(({ name }) => searchName === name);

    if (found) {
        return found.uid;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, if this is the primary use case for this data structure, it might make more sense for you to use an object keyed on `name` instead of an array.

For instance:

```
// Type of myList
myList: {[name: string]: { id: number, name: string, uid: string }} = {};

// Adding a new object
this.myList[myName] = { id: i, name: myName, uid: obj.UID };

// The new findByName implementation
findByName(searchName: string) {
    const found = this.myList[searchName];

    if (found) {
        return found.uid;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Doing that will mean you no longer have to search through the whole list.

Comment: Hello, I've tried both ways, exactly as you shown, but in both cases it is  `undefined` and does not returns existed value

Comment: Why are you adding a space to `this.searchName`? `' sally'` is not the same as `'sally'`

Comment: because in list of check-box values  it is added with space as you can see it in console log image, but even if  I search it without space, it is same result

Comment: The code works for me, are you correctly anticipating case-sensitivity? Your console image shows that all names begin with a space and a capital letter, meaning the code will not work unless the search name also has both a space and a capital letter.

Comment: @ casieber it has both, space and capital letter